# Updating values in a mysql database from a PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am querying the database, inserting the resultant values in an array then manipulating them and thereafter I want to update **each** of values in the affected rows using `mysql_update` from the array and that's where I am having trouble.

This is my code - kindly assist:

```
name   sellerid quantity
-------------------------
john       12     10
joel       23     20
brian      40     10
```

Let's take that as the query result and someone orders 25 items now the program is to take the items and assign them to one who ordered then deduct from the sellers.

```
$cursor="SELECT itemquantity,sellerid FROM mytable WHERE  price='$price'";                     
//it is a table containing data about people selling their commodities

$foundItems = array();

// likely to be a parameter of a function...
$totalUnitsOrdered = 25;

// maps user to amount assigned from him
$assignedQuantityPerUser = array();


while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $cursor ) ) {

  // Still order Quantity left?
  if ( 0 < $totalUnitsOrdered ) {

    if ( $row[ "itemquantity" ] <= $totalUnitsOrdered ) {
      if (!isset($assignedQuantityPerUser[$row["sellerid"]])) {
        $assignedQuantityPerUser[$row["sellerid"]] = 0;
      }

      // assign all of $row[ "itemquantity" ]
      $totalUnitsOrdered  -= 0 + $row[ "itemquantity" ];
      $assignedQuantityPerUser[ $row[ "sellerid" ] ] += 0 + $row[ "itemquantity" ];

    }  else {
      // assign all the rest: $totalUnitsOrdered
      $totalUnitsOrdered   = 0;
      $assignedQuantityPerUser[ $row[ "sellerid" ] ] += $totalUnitsOrdered;
    }
  }

  $newItem[] = $row[ "sellerid" ];
  $newItem[] = $row[ "itemquantity" ];

  // Append $newItem to the end of $foundItems 
  $foundItems[] = $newItem;
}
```

Comment: This question was already recently posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531487/undefined-index-error-from-a-php-arrya. I don't think it is clear enough, hence lack of response

Comment: @lng but clearly it is a different problem not similar to the one previously asked..tried simplifying it as best as i can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three cases (Algorithm )
this is pseudo code not exact code i hope you get the idea

```
while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($rec))
{
  if(quantity for user is  > total quantity ordered)
  {
    quantity of user -=total quantity ordered 
    update tableNamse set qty =quantity for user where userId=$row['id'];
    exit while
  }
  else if(quantity for user = total quantity ordered)
  {
     quantity of user=0;
    update tableNamse set qty =0 where userId=$row['id'];
    exit while
  }
  else
  {
     total quantity ordered - = quantity of user
    update tableNamse set qty =0 where userId=$row['id'];
    continue while loop
  }
 }
```

-- Update

```
   if($row['itemquantity'] > $totalUnitsOrdered)
   {
     $qtyUser=$row['itemquantity']-$totalUnitsOrdered;
     mysql_query("update tableName set itemQuantity=$qtyUser
                  where userId=$row['userId']" )
      break; // exit while
   }
```

--Update for third case

```
  else
{
$totalUnitsOrdered-=$row['itemquantity'];
mysql_query("update tableName set itemQuantity=0
                  where userId=$row['userId']" )

}
```

Comment: .thank you i get the idea.could you just kindly assist me with the code for even at least one of the cases.thanks.

Comment: i am having trouble coding the third case,kindly assist .thanks a lot.sorry for disturbing you,it's just that i am new to php and mysql.thanks

Comment: thanks but still on the third case(when $totalUnitsOrdered> $row['itemquantity'] at index 0,it should go to $row['itemquantity'] at index 1 and so on till $totalUnitsOrdered =0),how do i include a while loop to loop through the db till $totalUnitsOrdered =0 and update each of the rows,because currently it doesn't achieve that.thanks a lot.this is my main hurdle in the project.kindly assist me again.thanks Naveen

Comment: Is the code not working (3rd case), $totalUnitsOrdered is reduced by the current user amount and loop continue, inside firstly check `if($totalUnitsOrdered >0) break;`,

Comment: ,should it break if($totalUnitsOrdered >0) or if($totalUnitsOrdered =0),i think it's the second one